# Colocar label que é impressa em PHP dentro de uma div

Tags: php, html

Estou a querer mostra um registo da minha base de dados. utilizei PHP para criar, inserir e select. O problema é que quando mostro um registo, faz o `echo` dentro de uma `div` que é um Pop-up. O codigo PHP esta dentro da `div` Pop-up.

Exemplo:

```
function select($dir, $base){
  ...
  echo "<br><label><b>$affiche[title]</b></label><br>"
```

}

```
 if(isset($_POST['insert']))//code is good here!
            {

               select($dir, $base); //affiche évènements 
            }
```

E o codigo html:

```
<div id='abc' style="display:none"> </div>

    <div id="popup" style="display:none">

        <form method="POST" action="#">
           <input type=submit required  name='insert'>  
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Como faço para mostrar fora da `div`?

Comment: Como? Não percebi o seu problema...

Comment: O problema é que quero imprimir $affiche[title] (que é um campo da minha tabela) numa outra div. Nao sei se tem haver com o get.

Comment: A label é colocada na div popup. Eu quero colocar fora dessa div.

Comment: Reformule a questão pois no trecho HTML não há nenhum código PHP mas no contexto da questão fala de código PHP dentro da div "popup". Está bem confuso.

Comment: Quermo mostar esta label "echo "<br><label><b>$affiche[title]</b></label><br>"" fora da div "<div id="popup" style="display:none">" onde aparece.

Answer (score 1):

Você não precisa dar echo, faça assim:

```
$div = "seutexto";
```

Depois que você já tem o valor da variável você pode utilizar ele em qualquer lugar dentro do HTML (Desde que seja depois que a variável assumiu o valor) usando a tag:

```
<?= $div ?>
```

Ai você pode colocar essa tag fora da sua div, apontando para a variável.

Veja este tópico [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150238/php-variable-in-html-no-other-way-then-php-echo-var) para melhor resolução.